# Testing InlineFormset clean methods

Tags: python, django, django-forms, inline-formset

I have a Django project, with 2 models, a `Structure` and `Bracket`, the Bracket has a  ForeignKey to a Structure (i.e. one-to-many, one Structure has many Brackets). I created a `TabularInline` for the admin site, so that there would be a table of Brackets on the Structure. I added a custom formset with some a custom `clean` method to do some extra validation, you can't have a Bracket that conflicts with another Bracket on the same Structure etc.

The admin looks like this:

```
class BracketInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Bracket
    formset = BracketInlineFormset

class StructureAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        BracketInline
    ]
admin.site.register(Structure, StructureAdmin)
```

The `BracketInlineFormset` just has the clean method:

```
class BracketInlineFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        … my clean code here …
```

That all works, and the validation works.

However now I want to write some unittest to test my complex formset validation logic.

My first attempt to validate known-good values is:

```
data = {'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '1', 'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '0', 'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '', 'form-0-field1':'good-value', … }
formset = BracketInlineFormset(data)
self.assertTrue(formset.is_valid())
```

However that doesn't work and raises the exception:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: testValid (appname.tests.StructureTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/paht/to/project/tests.py", line 494, in testValid
    formset = BracketInlineFormset(data)
  File "/path/to/django/forms/models.py", line 672, in __init__
    self.instance = self.fk.rel.to()
AttributeError: 'BracketInlineFormset' object has no attribute 'fk'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation) (for formset validation) implies one can do this.

How come this isn't working? How do I test the custom clean()/validation for my inline formset?

Comment: What's the declaration of BracketInlineFormset look like?

Comment: @JohnMee inline formset code added to question

Answer (score 6):

You can use the inlineformset_factory method from django.forms.models to create a custom inline formset. This method sets the fk value to your formset based on the parent class passed on to it.

```
structure = StructureFactory() #foreign key
data = {'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '1', 'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '0', 'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '', 'form-0-field1':'good-value', … }
BIFormset = inlineformset_factory(Structure, Bracket, formset=BracketInlineFormset)
formset = BIFormset(data, prefix='form', instance=structure) 
self.assertTrue(formset.is_valid())
```

Note the `formset=BracketInlineFormset` parameter while constructing the formset with the factory.

Reference: [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.inlineformset_factory)